# import confusion for python packages

Tags: python, python-import

`enter code here`I have both a package name celery and a filename celery.

When I say import celery its trying import the celery file instead of celery package. And it says it's unable to import the Celery

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery


celery = Celery('celery_app',
                broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
                backend='amqp://',
                include=['celery_app.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

Like below. Is there way to explain that importing the package instead of the file.

**Edit:**

Tried

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
del sys.path[0]
from celery import Celery
```

But still the same. When I try those commands from python shell; it does not give any error.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Why do you have a module and a package with the same name?  You need to change one of them.

Comment: @BrenBarn: this should be possible, though. The stdlib just keeps growing and you can't anticipate every future addition to it.

Comment: @larsmans: In some sense that's true, but there's no way around that.  No matter what you name your package, someone else (including the stdlib) could make another module with that name.  In the last resort you can always manipulate `sys.path` to search paths in the order you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try those commands from python shell; it does not give any error. Is there something that I am missing?

I really **don't** recommend it, **RENAME** your file as everyone says, but you could possibly try

```
import sys, os
[sys.path.remove(i) for i in sys.path if i == os.getcwd() or i == '']
from celery import Celery
```

Also, you're importing `absolute_import` but you don't seem to be using it ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports)). When importing from your *local* file `celery.py`

```
from .celery import my_func
```

Comment: I tried but same, i said print i, and it shows the current directory.But still unable to import

Comment: Hmm, have you got the `[sys.path...]` line **above** the `import celery` line?

Comment: I hate to say it, but it works for me. Try inspecting things like `celery.__file__` and listing `for p in sys.path: print p` to debug what exactly is going on.

Comment: it first shows when i say print celery.__file__ 
my the current directory then the package folder